# How to write array of bytes of type UInt32 to OutputStream in swift

Tags: ios, swift, outputstream

I am trying to write array of bytes of type UInt32 to OutputStream.
I have tried something like this:

```
 var byteArr: Array<UInt8> = []
    let header : [UInt32] = [30194250, 2, 3000, 0x782b415d, 0, 0]
    
    for i in 0...5 {
        var bigEndian = header[i].bigEndian
               let count = MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size
               let bytePtr = withUnsafePointer(to: &bigEndian) {
                 $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: count) {
                   UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: count)
                 }
               }
        byteArr.append(contentsOf: bytePtr)
    }
   
    print(byteArr)

            outputStream?.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(byteArr), maxLength: byteArr.count)
```

but i get an error `2020-08-27 16:30:25.559888+0800 SocketConnectionTest[32297:26213693] SocketStream read error [0x6000020ce340]: 1 54 stream event NSStreamEvent(rawValue: 8) The operation couldn't be completed. Connection reset by peer stream event NSStreamEvent(rawValue: 8) The operation couldn't be completed. Connection reset by peer`

Any suggestions please. what am i missing?